# jquery DateTimePicker validation for dd/mm/yy is not working correctly

Tags: datetimepicker, date-format, jquery-validate

I'm new in jquery. In my MVC project most of the validations are done in jquery. All are working fine expect this date field. Let me describe my problem.

I have a date textbox, which is attached to datetimepicker. My code is below.

$("#DateTimeTextBox").datetimepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            timeFormat: 'hh:mm'
        });

For validating this field i'm using this code

'DateTimeTextBox': {
      required: true,
      date: true
    },

Here if we give the date format is 'mm/dd/yy'  for datetimepicker the validation is showing correct. if we give the date format like this 'dd/mm/yy', always show the validation error message "Please enter a valid date". But I'm giving the correct date like "25/11/2012".

Is there anywhere need to set the date format for validation.

Thanks

Bobbin Paulose

Answer (score 0):

The [additional-methods.js](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/blob/master/additional-methods.js) file is bundled with jquery validate and has a bunch of useful methods including a method 'dateITA' that you can use to validate a date in the format dd/mm/yyy.  Download the latest query validate code here.

[https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/)

Add a reference to additional-methods.js in your page, and use the rule 'dateITA' instead of 'date'.

Comment: I have different types of format. User can specify the format like mm/dd/yy, dd/mm/yy, d/m/y. Anything user can specify